# How to exclude/ignore owner's review vote(+2) to submit in Gerrit patchset

Tags: prolog, gerrit, review

I want to stop patchset's owner to review and vote on their patchset in Gerrit. Currenlty i am using the follwoing code -

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H | Rest], Sum) :- sum_list(Rest,Tmp), Sum is H + Tmp.

add_category_min_score(In, Category, Min,  P) :-
    findall(2, gerrit:commit_label(label(Category,2),R),Z),
    sum_list(Z, Sum),
    Sum >= Min, !,
    gerrit:commit_label(label(Category, V), U),
    V >= 1,
    !,
    P = [label(Category,ok(U)) | In].

add_category_min_score(In, Category,Min,P) :-
    P = [label(Category,need(Min)) | In].

submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    gerrit:remove_label(Ls,label('Code-Review',_),NoCR),
    add_category_min_score(NoCR,'Code-Review', 4, Labels),
    S =.. [submit | Labels].
```

I tried the following - [Example - 8](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#NonAuthorCodeReview) and [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560812/exclude-author-from-gerrit-review#)

Any help would be appriciable, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the access rights by adding this to the access rights :

```
[access "refs/heads/*"]
    label-Code-Review = block -2..+2 group Change Owner
```

Comment: For this, group change owner should be there. As i mentioned in questions, it does not work

Comment: Any idea why this build in group is not available? How old is your Gerrit version?

Comment: I am using Powered by Gerrit Code Review (2.16.15).

Comment: got one more response on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/4SceYS3n22E/1UxI9FDjCAAJ about the same but undortunately that's nto working too